# Expanding NSOutlineView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

My requirement is something like that,

On top of NSOutlineview there would be a search textfield and NSOutline view may contains the nested Groups,

if a item / row is matching with the search query, then it should be displayed, which its all parent node till root level,

the way i am doing is as follows,

1 -- Depending upon the what user has entered , re-building tne NSOutlineview datasource ( Nothing but an NSArray )

2 -- Have implemented all delegate method,

Now my problem is Group is not getting expanded automatically, I know i should call

```
-expandItem:expandChildren:,
```

but my questions is from where i should call this, **i called it after reload data but it didn't work**

i tried to call it something like this ,,,,

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    if(aTableColumn == nil){
        [self log:@"aTableColumn is NIL "];
        return nil;
    }   
    if([[aTableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"firstColumn"] ){
        if ( [myOutlineView shouldExpandIt:item]){
            [myOutineView expandItem:item];
        }
        return item;
    }
    return item;
}
```

but its faulting perhaps going to recursive loop

Any other way to achieve the same.

Comment: I would make sure it is not called while processing other delegate or data source methods. You could try to make a delayed call, for instance by using `dispatch_async` on the main thread.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are "rebuilding the data srource" are u removing obcts etc? is your search feature filtering/removing objects from the NSArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all of you to look into this,

By putting log, i found out to be , it seems to be [NSOutlineView reloadData ] seems to be blocking call,

so after that if i need to expand / collapse group , i am using

```
  [pCTOutlineView expandItem:pValue];
```

and working so far....

Comment: @zic10 its a node value that you would like to expand

Comment: If you use NSTreeController/NSArrayController. You have to get an appropriate TreeNode and use it as pValue in the example above? Like: "[[self.outlineViewController arrangedObjects] childNodes][i]".

Comment: I think he is using DataSource protocol, and not an Array/Tree controller (usually used on conjunction with Cocoa-Bindings)